# Converting ctypes.c_void_p to PyCapsule

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a python method in one library that returns a function handle as a `ctypes.c_void_p`. I need to pass the handle to another library that expects it as a capsule. How can I convert the `c_void_p` into a capsule to facilitate this interop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
import ctypes
PyCapsule_Destructor = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.py_object)
PyCapsule_New = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_New
PyCapsule_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
PyCapsule_New.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p, PyCapsule_Destructor)
capsule = PyCapsule_New(0xdeadbeef, None, PyCapsule_Destructor(0))
```

Comment: I haven't given this a full test run yet but my first impressions are that this is a good solution. Thanks! This was a surprisingly tricky one to research!

Comment: I'm now using this and can confirm that it works.