How to csat WinID handle to capsule in pyside6
In pyqt, one can access wid as sip.voidptr, using widget.winId(), and then turn it to capsule object using wid.ascapsule()
In pyside6, when using widget.winId(), I can only get an int number.
How can I get winId() as ptr like pyqt when using pyside6?
I need ptr as capsule because the api I use give the following error:
return WNT_Window(ctypes.c_void_p(wid))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. OCP.WNT.WNT_Window(theTitle: str, theClass: OCP.WNT.WNT_WClass, theStyle: int, thePxLeft: int, thePxTop: int, thePxWidth: int, thePxHeight: int, theBackColor: OCP.Quantity.Quantity_NameOfColor = <Quantity_NameOfColor.Quantity_NOC_MATRAGRAY: 2>, theParent: capsule = None, theMenu: capsule = None, theClientStruct: capsule = None)
    2. OCP.WNT.WNT_Window(theHandle: capsule, theBackColor: OCP.Quantity.Quantity_NameOfColor = <Quantity_NameOfColor.Quantity_NOC_MATRAGRAY: 2>)


Why do you need a capsule object? Why not just convert the voidptr to an int?

I need to pass winId to WNT_Window(), come from ocp, which takes a ptr.

Try using ctypes to create the capsule from the void ptr: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65056619/984421.

I can only get int when using pyside6, I can't get void ptr.

But you can create a void ptr from the wid using ctypes.

Please, give me more details

One way or another, you must make ctypes do what PySide cannot do. I already suggested something to try in my comment above: i.e. use ctypes.pythonapi to create a PyCapsule with result-type c_void_p. Something like the following might work: GP = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer; GP.restype = ctypes.c_void_p; GP.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]; capsule = GP(widget.winId(), None). (I cannot test any of this myself as I don't have access to a Windows system).

Finally get it works, with great thanks to @ekhumoro.
My solution:
1.convert winId to void_pointer
wid = widget.winId
ptr = ctypes.cast(wid, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p)) 


create PyCapsule

PyCapsule_Destructor = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.py_object)
PyCapsule_New = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCapsule_New
PyCapsule_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
PyCapsule_New.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p, PyCapsule_Destructor)
capsule = PyCapsule_New(ptr, None, PyCapsule_Destructor(0))

